# Solution to the sum of k-step path lengths between node pairs in directed weighted graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, adjacency-matrices

In a non weighted graph, the adjacency matrix ($A$) raised to the power $k$ will return the number of k-step paths between nodes $i$ and $j$ at the entry $a_{ij}$. Is there an equivalent for weighted graphs? I.e. to obtain the *sum of the cumulative weights of all paths* between node pairs?

Applying the same approach as above, but to a weighted adjacency matrix, i.e. raising to the power $k$, returns the *sum of the product of the weights along each $k$ step path* between node pairs. This is useful when edge weight represents some probability (e.g. Markov models), however not when edge weight represents a length (e.g. geospatial network).

**Note** I want to avoid path search algorithms (e.g. Dijkstra's or Yen's) if possible, as this will be applied to very large networks so efficiency is important.

**Example**: Given a 4-node digraph (image linked below), with the weighted adjacency matrix (infinity represents no connection between nodes):

[Digraph described in the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhxz1.png)

$$A =
\begin{matrix}
\infty & 2 & 3 & \infty \\
2 & \infty & 5 & 1 \\
\infty & \infty & \infty & 7 \\
\infty & 1 & \infty & \infty \\
\end{matrix}
$$

where e.g. the connection between nodes B & C is of length 5. I want to find the n-step length matrix, which for the 2 step case would be:

$$A_2 =
\begin{matrix}
4 &\infty & 7 & 13 \\
\infty & 6 & 5 & 12 \\
\infty & 8 & \infty & \infty \\
3 & \infty & 6 & 2 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A^k_{i,j} = (n^k_{i,j}, s^k_{i,j})$ where $n^k_{i,j}$ is the number of paths of length $k$ between $i$ and $j$, and $s^k_{i,j}$ is the sum of the lengths between these paths.
$A^1_{i,j} = (1, w_{i,j})$ if $ij$ is an edge, else $A^1_{i,j}=(0,0)$
The idea of the recurrence is that a $(k+k')$-step path from $i$ to $j$ is composed of a $k$-step path from $i$ to an intermediate vertex $c$  followed by a $k'$-step path from $c$ to $j$.
Let fix $c$. Let $n_1$ (resp $n_2$) be the number of $k$-step paths from $i$ to $c$ (resp. $k'$-step paths from $c$ to $j$) and $s_1$ (resp. $s_2$) the sum of weigths on these paths.
We can easily see that the number of $(k+k')$-step paths from $i$ to $j$ passing through $c$ at step $k$ is $n_1n_2$. The sum of weights is $s_1n_2 + s_2n_1$ because each path from $i$ to $c$ will appear in exactly $n_2$ paths, and conversely. To get the total number of $(k+k')$-step paths from $i$ to $j$, we just need to sum over the $c$. So the recurrence is given by :
$$A^{k+k'}_{i,j} = (n^{k+k'}_{i,j}, s^{k+k'}_{i,j}) = \sum_{c\in V}(n^k_{i,c}n^{k'}_{c,j}, n^k_{i,c}s^{k'}_{c,j}+s^k_{i,c}n^{k'}_{c,j})$$

We can adapt the definition of the matrix multiplication by replacing the multiplication by :
$(n_1,s_1)\otimes(n_2,s_2) = (n_1n_2, n_1s_2 + n_2s_1)$
and addition by :
$(n_1,s_1)\oplus(n_2,s_2) = (n_1+n_2, s_1+s_2)$
With it, we have :
$$A^{k+k'}_{i,j} = \bigoplus_{c\in V} A^{k}_{i,c}\otimes A^{k'}_{c,j}$$
and so $A^kA^{k'} = A^{k+k'}$

The new matrix multiplication is associative, so matrix exponentiation by squaring still work.

---

This kind of redefinition of the matrix multiplication is common when dealing with shortest paths, see the [min-plus matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-plus_matrix_multiplication)

Comment: But how does this answer the question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You just need to compute $A^k_{i,j}$, using exponentiation by squaring for efficiency.

Comment: Note that this requires non-edges to be represented by $(0, 0)$ instead of $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: Yes, this is important to note, I edited.

Comment: Thanks @caduk for the answer. I don't fully understand what you're proposing unfortunately, are you able to clarify any further and/or offer an example? Also, are the multiplication and addition functions displayed as they are to represent max-plus algebra, or matrix algebra more generally?

Comment: Yes, this is a similar construct as the min-plus matrix multiplication, but with a recurrence relation adapted to the problem. I will try to clarify the recurrence.

Comment: Hi @caduk, thanks so much for updating, it's a lot clearer now and have no problem following up to, and including, the equation following "...recurrence is given by:". I'm still unsure about how I'd actually implement this and if there's a way to do so other than calculate element-by-element. I'm assuming there is a way to achieve the result using a matrix-wide operation, given what you have suggested elsewhere, but I'm not sure of what that would look like. Any further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For matrix multiplication, you can go with a naive implementation in $n^3$, but almost all algorithmic results of matrix multiplication are generic enough to work with elements of a ring (here, you even have a field, because the multiplication is invertible), so you can use the powerful machinery of matrix theory. Many libraries of linear algebra have an efficient generic implementation of matrix implementation, like BLAS. You can implement such a specialization very easily in Julia using LinearAlgebra.jl. or in python using Numpy.

Comment: For matrix exponentiation, you can use the squaring by exponentiation, which takes only $log(n)$ multiplication of matrices, but good libraries should provide also this functionality. All in all, the complexity is $n^3log(n)$ with naive matrix multiplication, and becomes $n^{\omega}log(n)$ with $\omega$ a better exponent using for example the Strassen algorithm.

Comment: Sorry @caduk, my confusion is more related to the structure of the matrix **_A_**. From your answer, my understanding is that it is a matrix of size **_N x N_**, in which each element is a 2 element vector, the first being **_n_** and the second, **_s_**. Is that correct? And then I can square that matrix using the regular matrix multiplication or exponentiation operations? TIA

Comment: yes, that's correct